# `require': cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I am attempting to run a test against a hello method contained within the hello file:

```
ruby hello_spec.rb
```

which returns:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from hello_spec.rb:116:in `<main>'
```

The files are contained within the same directory. I've installed RSpec and (I believe) the necessary gems. Other people seem to have similar problems but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I am running Ruby 2.1.2 
I am new to Ruby and am struggling (obviously) to get the environment properly configured. Any help is much appreciated.

Note: I didn't write any of the test code. I've literally only made the hello.rb file.

Comment: try the "load" command instead of "require"?

load 'hello_spec.rb'

require load file only once in ruby.

in "load" ruby source file is included.

Comment: From within the REPL? I get the same thing.

Comment: tr load './hello_spec.rb'

Comment: Is your spec_helper.rb file configured properly?

Comment: Still no, thank you for trying though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `require 'hello'` to `require_relative 'hello'` in your `hello_spec.rb`. Current directory is not included in default ruby load path by default.

Or, alternatively, add the current directory to ruby load path:

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Hope it helps.